# Strip text from output in rhel

Tags: linux, awk

So im trying to strip away some of the text from this output using awk
This is my output ,

```
href="/warning:understand-how-this-works!/5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsrePxLM2Uo">+</a>
href="/warning:understand-how-this-works!/5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsrePxLM2Uo">+</a>
href="/warning:understand-how-this-works!/5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsrePxLM2Uo">+</a>
```

Basically, I am trying to take that info, from the output of a text file,Remove this part:

```
href="/warning:understand-how-this-works!/
```

and this part

```
">+</a>
```

So it only shows:

```
5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsrePxLM2Uo
```

or, outputs that. 
Running on centos 6

Comment: Show your awk attempt and ask a specific question related to that attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{sub(/.*!\//,X,$0);sub(/\".*/,X,$0);print}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what I was looking for. I was trying to use -F but that ended up leaving a trailing \ on there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` if you want:

```
grep -oP '!/\K.*?(?=")' inputfile
```

Or `awk` by playing around `FS` :

```
awk -F'!/|">' '{print $2}' input
```

Or use `sed` backrefrencing:

```
sed -r 's/(^.*\!\/)(.*?)(">.*)/\2/g' input
```